# Laravel - Prevent Multiple Login Of Same Credentials (logoutOtherDevices)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel web app where multiple users login but I need to prevent login if the user has already logged.

I know that Laravel has a method (logoutOtherDevices) to logout the user when a second user (same credentials) is login. But this method do not show any message when logout the user. I would like to inform the logged out user that another user has logged in.

How can I implement something like that?